# Microsoft Graph Delegated permissions show all tenants data

Tags: oauth-2.0, permissions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to build an app that lists the teams that the current user is member of in Microsoft Teams using the Microsoft Graph API and the user should only be able to see her own teams.

The problem is that the app gets access to ALL teams on the tenant and not only the teams that the user already belongs to.

This is an issue because even just the naming of a private team can be confidential information in some organizations.

According to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) the least privileged permission for listing Groups is “GroupMember.Read.All”.

I therefore create an app with this permission and the type is “Delegated”.

[image: App delegated permissions]

Since the permission requires admin consent I manually give admin consent to the app in the AAD Portal.

I now ask the user to authorize the app on her behalf by having her follow this link:

```
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant]/
oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[clientId]
&redirect_uri=[redirectUri]
&response_type=code
&response_mode=query
&prompt=consent
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read offline_access`
```

Through the OAUTH2 flow the server obtains an access token for the user and the delegated permissions. The access token is used to call the Graph API mentioned before:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')

The issue is that the request returns ALL teams on the tenant and not only the teams that the user has access to in MS Teams client - including a long list of private teams that the user should not be able to see at all.

How can it be that the access token obtained from the user approving the app gives the app access to all teams and not just the teams that the user is member of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two endpoints that can be useful for you

First endpoint

```
GET /me/joinedTeams
```

gets the teams that the user is a direct member of.

The second one

```
GET /users/{user-id}/teamwork/associatedTeams
```

gets the list of teams that the user is a direct member of a team or is a member of a shared channel that is hosted inside a team.

Documentation:

[List joined teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[List associated teams info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/associatedteaminfo-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Yes, that works.

With the "GET /me/joinedTeams" endpoint I don't get excess data, which is essential for my customers using the app.

Still surprised that the /groups-endpoint returns more data (teams) than the delegated user has access to, though.

Answer (score 0):

To access group members ,least privileged permission is “GroupMember.Read.All”. but looking at your question , looks like you are trying to get list of members for specific MS teams Channel , if i am not wrong , this doc will help you  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http .

Hope this help ,please feel free to ask question in comment box if you are looking for something else.

Thanks

Comment: Vicky, thanks, but I'm not trying to get list of members. I need to list the teams that a user is member of in the MS Teams client - and you can use the "GroupMember" permission for this as the least privileged permission.

My expected outcome is that the app would only have access to a list of teams that is exactly the same as the one the user is seeing in the client. Hence, the surprise when I discovered that the app get access to a list of ALL teams based on accesstoken created based on the user-specific consent.